# The opeartor set doesn't work in mongodb. Or any other methods to add a new field into the document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

*The operator **$set** can't add a new field **hide***. I thought, I was doing everything according to the mongodb official documentation. Can somebody tall me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks

```
  createClass
    .updateMany(
      { classname: req.body.className },
      { $set : {"hide":true}},
      { multi: true, upsert: false },
    )
```

Here is the schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const Classes = new Schema({
  classname: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  Subject: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  Chapter: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  Topic: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  SubjectimgPath: {
    type: String,
  },
  ChapterimgPath: {
    type: String,
  },
  TopicimgPath: {
    type: String,
  },
  content: {
    type: Array,
  }
});

Classes.index({ "$**": "text" });

const Createclass = mongoose.model("AllClasses", Classes);

module.exports = Createclass;
```

Comment: show schema pls

Comment: you don't have a key hide in schema how you can set it??

Comment: Yeah, I've added, please check above

Comment: Omg, I'm so stupid. Thank you so much Pardeep Baboria. I'm just beginning with mongo so... Nevertheless, Thanks guys, especially Pardeep Baboria

Comment: dtw its common at beginning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
const Classes = new Schema({
 classname: {
 type: String,
 required: true,
 },
   Subject: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
 },
 Chapter: {
 type: String,
 required: true,
},
 Topic: {
type: String,
required: true,
 },
SubjectimgPath: {
type: String,
  },
  ChapterimgPath: {
   type: String,
 },
  TopicimgPath: {
  type: String,
 },
 content: {
type: Array,
 }
}, {strict :false} );
```